# VLOOKUP works with FormulaR1C1 but not Regular Formula?

Tags: vba, excel

I posted another question that was close to this question earlier but it is actually different. I have this VLOOKUP code that takes input from a user to get the file to use the VLOOKUP with. It works in my one macro when I run the whole thing, but if I run the private sub by itself, I get an error message 1004 on the first VLOOKUP line. I then tried changing the code to use FormulaR1C1, and it ended up working correctly using that version. Why won't it work using my current code but it works when I use FormulaR1C1?

```
Sub NEWTRY()
'
' Create_VLOOKUP_Using_Old_Kronos_Full_File Macro
'

'

Dim iRet As Integer
Dim strPrompt As String
Dim strTitle As String

' Promt
strPrompt = "Please select the last Kronos Full File before the dates of this HCM Report." & vbCrLf & _
    "This will be used to find the Old Position, Org Unit, and Old Cost Center." & vbCrLf & _
    "For example, if the date of this report is 7-28-17 thru 8-25-17, the closest Kronos Full File you would want to use is 7-27-17."

' Dialog's Title
strTitle = "Last Kronos Full File for Old Positions"

'Display MessageBox
iRet = MsgBox(strPrompt, vbOK, strTitle)

Dim LR As Long
Dim X As String
Dim lNewBracketLocation As Long

X = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
    FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*),*.xls*", _
    Title:="Choose the Kronos Full File.", MultiSelect:=False)

Dim wbk As Workbook
Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=X, ReadOnly:=True)

Dim shtName As String
shtName = wbk.Worksheets(1).name
wbk.Close

MsgBox "You selected " & X
'Find the last instance in the string of the path separator "\"
lNewBracketLocation = InStrRev(X, Application.PathSeparator)
'Edit the string to suit the VLOOKUP formula - insert "["
X = Left$(X, lNewBracketLocation) & "[" & Right$(X, Len(X) - lNewBracketLocation)

Range("T2").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC11,'" & X & "]'!R3C2:R9846C49,13,0)"
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("U2").Formula = "=VLOOKUP($E2,'" & X & "]'!$B$1:$AP$99999,41,0)"
Range("V2").Formula = "=VLOOKUP($E2,'" & X & "]shtName'!$B$1:$AP$99999,18,0)"
```

The issue is I believe in the last 3 lines, or how it is reading X and putting that in there. The last 3 lines with the VLOOKUPS is where it errors except now the first line with R1C1 actually works. I was trying other versions with the other lines but they don't work.

I would rather not use the R1C1 but it doesn't want to work unless I use it.

Comment: try putting the formula in place with the R1C1 style, then use `.Formula` to see what it looks like in the A1 style

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Is there an easy way to convert it automatically? Near the end of the code the first VLOOKUP line is in the R1C1 style and that one actually works. But then it errors on the next line. Am I able to take that R1C1 line and convert it to A1 not by doing it manually?

Comment: you have this command `Range("T2").FormulaR1C1`. if you stop execution at that point, you should be able to see what it looks like in the A1 style, if you `?Range("T2").Formula` in the immediate window. that should help you alter the formula to the style you prefer

Comment: ohhhh NICE I will try that! someone just mentioned the Immediate window in a past question I had and I didn't really know how to use it. I will try it.

Comment: Alright So I used that command in Immediate window. I then Redid it so X was the variable and it looked just like my other one but it worked. So then I looked what was different and it looks like in my R1C1 style one it was only going until Row 9846 or something. But my other ones were going to Row 99999. As soon as I changed it to 9846 it worked instantly. and even when it was 9999. But it will not work when I put it to 99999. Do you know why this is? I didn't think I had too many rows but it was not working for some reason.

Comment: file format? xls only goes to 16384

Comment: ahhh hmmm... maybe. I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

So, you're trying to do a lookup on a sheet whose name is the last part of the selected path?

Add a line `msgbox x` before your lookups so you can make sure that `x` is being calculated as you intended...  For me it returned:

```
c:\path\[filename.xlsm
```

What is an example of `x` ? 
...the 3 formulas getting pasted in are:

```
=VLOOKUP(RC11,'c:\path\[filename.xlsm]'!R3C2:R9846C49,13,0)
=VLOOKUP($E2,'c:\path\[filename.xlsm]'!$B$1:$AP$99999,41,0)
=VLOOKUP($E2,'c:\path\[filename.xlsm]shtName'!$B$1:$AP$99999,18,0)
```

Comment: yes that is basically it. Which you select that path by using a explore window and click on the file you want. So the filename should be coming over correctly and you think so too with how you typed them in for the full formula in your second part. SO I am not sure why I am getting this error.

Comment: Alright So I used that command that someone else recommded in the Immediate window. I then Redid it so X was the variable and it looked just like my other one but it worked. So then I looked what was different and it looks like in my R1C1 style one it was only going until Row 9846 or something. But my other ones were going to Row 99999. As soon as I changed it to 9846 it worked instantly. and even when it was 9999. But it will not work when I put it to 99999. Do you know why this is? I didn't think I had too many rows but it was not working for some reason